# what is the default password when you create new user in ubuntu?

Tags: password, useradd

I have created a new user by using `useradd` command e.g.:

```
sudo useradd acreddy
```

Then new user is created but it is asking for a password what is the password?

Comment: Start using `adduser` instead of `useradd`

Comment: There is no default password. When you create a user it does not have a password yet, so you cannot login with that username until you create a password. There is one other way to act as a new user without its password. As root type `su - acreddy`. It will not ask for password and you will be logged in as acreddy. But only in that terminal.

Comment: @nobody it still asked me for the password even with `-`

Comment: @DanM. You have to be root. So try `sudo -i` to switch to root. Then try `sudo - <username>`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to set a password for the user. Use the `passwd` command:

`Usage: passwd [options] [LOGIN]`

So if you want to set a password for the new user, you type in:

```
sudo passwd acreddy
```

and you're good.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to set password, you can do it by

```
passwd -d username
```